# set_value() default in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've used formigniter to generate a form for CI. http://formigniter.org/

That bit works great. However I want to set a default value for the name field.

The input code looks like this:

```
<label for="forename">Forename</label>
<?php echo form_error('forename'); ?>
<br /><input id="forename" type="text" name="forename" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo set_value('forename'); ?>"  />
```

and I'd want to add in the first name with `$this->session->userdata('current_client');`

Will it break my database insert if I just drop it into the set_value function?

**Edit:**

Sorry I don't think I was very clear there. I want the name field to be automatically filled in with the name from the session cookie.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you're properly escaping input data before running the query, it shouldn't cause any problems. The set_value function just sets the value, the only benefit to using it is it simplifies setting the value to an already submitted value when redisplaying the form or showing a default value when the form has yet to be submitted.

This would use the session var as the default value for the form field:

```
<input id="forename" type="text" name="forename" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo set_value('forename', $this->session->userdata('current_client')); ?>"  />
```

Comment: Ah yes, I just figured this out...by reading the documentation. Probably should do that first in future. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html Thanks for your reply brabym.

Answer (score 0):

Same case with I case

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'qty_' . $i, 
    'size'=>15, 
    'id' => 'qty_' . $i,
    'required'=>'required', 
    'class'=>'input-small',
    'value' => set_value('qty_' . $i),
    $restock_thirty
);

echo form_input($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter, if generate an error in controller code suppose username unfilled then return an error but the page can refresh, then set_value can set that text box value

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username.." value="<?php echo set_value('username') ?>" class="form-control tx">
```