# CI set default value for form input

Tags: php, codeigniter, time

I have this form code in view:

```
<div>
    <label for="password">Post Time:</label> 
    <?php set_value('post_time') = date('H:i:s'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="post_time" value="<?=set_value('post_time')?>">
</div>
```

I just want to set the present time in the textbox. What ive tried is to set it with this directly:

```
<?php set_value('post_time') = date('H:i:s'); ?>
```

But it gives me the error:

```
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context...
```

How can i do this. Iam just new to CodeIgniter.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="post_time" value="<?=set_value('post_time', date('H:i:s'));?>">
```

[set_value() default in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873601/set-value-default-in-code-igniter)

[Another relevant link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a value beside the re-populated one you need to pass that as second argument:

```
<div>
    <label for="password">Post Time:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="post_time" value="<?=set_value('post_time', date('H:i:s'));?>">
</div>
```

Now, if the "post_time" index is not set, the result of date() will be shown.